# Tool to identify potential reviewers for a proposed change

Tags: git, code-reviews

Is there a tool that takes as input a proposed patch and a git repository, and identifies the developers are the best candidates for reviewing the patch? It would use the git history to identify the authors that have the most experience with the files / sections of code that are being changed.

*Edit:* The use case is a large open source project ([OpenStack Compute](https://github.com/openstack/nova)), where merge proposals come in, and I see a merge proposal on a chunk of code I'm not familiar with, and I want to add somebody else's name to the list of suggested reviewers so that person gets a notification to look at the merge proposal.

Comment: It's bad (totally wrong) idea to suggest ordinary code-monkey as reviewer of code based on file-history

Comment: @Lazy: Why? Whats wrong with what the OP is looking for, and why is "It's bad (totally wrong)...." ?  I see such a tool as being very useful in my workplace.

Comment: @mattnz - nothing wrong with "what the OP is looking for", if it is *automated method of routing CR to the right person* in common and if such tool exist. Totally wrong (without relation to any tool) **idea** (repeat myself) "**suggest ordinary code-monkey** as reviewer of new code based on file-history". Code and task-responsibility (over code) **may be different things**

Comment: Sorry -difference in ideas of code review purpose - we don't employ "code monkeys". In my workplace we are all equals (some may be more equal then others), Code review is used for the purpose of teaching as well as code quality, so all are expected to be reviewers, and all expected to be reviewed.

Comment: How do you want to quantify "most experience"? Most lines of code? Most recent edits? If I wrote an entire file/module a year ago and haven't touched it sense, and someone else made a few minor changes last week, who is suitable? I'm not sure how you can automatically determine the best candidates with any reasonable amount of certainty...

Comment: @ThomasOwens I'm not looking for a fully automated process, just a heuristic to provide some additional information. Providing multiple metrics (most lines of code, most recent edits) would be useful.

Comment: Could you edit that information into your question? When I read it, I assumed a fully automated process that was statistically valid.

Comment: @ThomasOwens I added more details to the question.

Answer (score 8):

I'm not aware of any such tool, but a baseline one is easy enough to write:

```
(for file in $files_touched_by_patch; do
    git blame -p "$file"
done) \
  | grep '^author ' | sed 's/^author *//' \
  | sort | uniq -c | sort -nrk 1
```

will list the people who last touched `$files_touched_by_patch`, sorted by how many of their lines of code survive in the current version.

Answer (score 0):

The Git project has [git contacts](https://git.seveas.net/manpages/git-contacts.html) in its `contrib/` directory.

> Given a set of changes, specified as patch files or revisions,
> determine people who might be interested in those changes. This is
> done by consulting the history of each patch or revision hunk to find
> people mentioned by commits which touched the lines of files under
> consideration.